# Accessing with credentials

Tags: html, url, google-chrome

I'm developing a web site which needs to access to a url that need username and password.

What I am doing so far is access the url with the data, I mean:

> http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@coolwebsite.com/securedContent

This works on firefox and Google Chrome(18.0.1025.168m)
But when I updated it to 190.1084.46m is not working anymore.

Any idea about why it is working no more on that chrome version?
Or any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is a conscious decision on the part of the Chrome team. Embedding usernames/passwords in URLs is no longer supported in newer versions of Chrome according to [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150).

Comment: That's so bad... How can GC do that :( I'm truly disappointed. Do you know a way to workaround it? Thanks so much

Comment: You can vote for the issue in the issue tracker by starring it, or look for one that more directly asks for the feature to be re-added. The comment thread also includes a few people discussing workarounds, one of which is a Chrome extension. Maybe worth a shot.

Comment: I already checked the Chrome extension but it's not what I'm looking for :(. Thanks so much for the help